# Show only the entered date and the value corresponding to the value entered in the combo box in the table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is a button that receives `modelname` (species) and date. This code shows corresponding to selected date but can't show selected modelname that is selected in combobox. If I get modelname A/B, I want to show values that have `<td>A</td>` or `<td>B</td>`.

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  var modelname = document.getElementById("model")
  var from = startdate;
  var to = enddate;

  if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
    return;
  }

  from = from || '1970-01-01'; // default from to a old date if it is not set
  to = to || '2999-12-31';

  var dateFrom = moment(from);
  var dateTo = moment(to);

  $('#testTable tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    var val = $(tr).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
    var dateVal = moment(val, "YYYY-MM-DD");
    var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, [])) ? "" : "none"; // [] for inclusive
    $(tr).css('display', visible);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="testTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>species</th>
      <th>Num1</th>
      <th>Num2</th>
      <th>Num3</th>
      <th>Num4</th>
      <th>Num5</th>
      <th>Num6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td><text class="dateselect">2021-05-16</text></td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>153</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><text class="dateselect">2021-05-17</text></td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>153</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><text class="dateselect">2021-05-18</text></td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>153</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>150</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-shadow" id="btn1" type="submit">input</button>
</div>
```

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hklAQ.png)

Comment: Can you please add the HTML to the question so we can create a working example of the issue

Comment: <table id="testTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>species</th>
            <th>Num1</th>
            <th>Num2</th>
            <th>Num3</th>
            <th>Num4</th>
            <th>Num5</th>
            <th>Num6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><text class = "dateselect">2021-05-16</text></td>
        <td>6000</td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td>153</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>150</td>
    </tr>

Comment: <tr>
        <td><text class = "dateselect">2021-05-17</text></td>
        <td>6000</td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td>153</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><text class = "dateselect">2021-05-18</text></td>
        <td>6000</td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td>153</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

Comment: There is no id named model in your html. The variables startdate and enddate is not initialized. A Button is not created and a comobox too. Update your question and deliver the whole html code.

Comment: I can't include code in this question so I attached an code image.